# Is there a way I can attach JWT token to axios http requests in NextJS app router project

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js 13 with app router and looking for a way to add authorization header to the axios http request.

I have created an instance in the following way, The code expects to receive JWT token from the cookie but gets undefined even if there is cookie set in the browser.

```
import { getJWTCookie } from "@/utils/cookie";

import axios from "axios";

let cookie = getJWTCookie();

const userHTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

userHTTP.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (cookie) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${cookie}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default userHTTP;
```

On console logging the cookie here is what I get:

```
  ' ~ cookie:',
  undefined
  ' ~ cookie:',
  undefined
  ' ~ cookie:',
'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NDhiMzMwYmMyZDU0YmU5OGY2ZjhlNjkiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkFha2FzaHgyODM4IiwiaWF0IjoxNjg2OTc1ODA0LCJleHAiOjE2ODk1Njc4MDR9.IsAtdoN7llMvQIQE_owHSE0f1FHP3vDN8RpgFP6yesE'
```

Here is how I am setting and getting the cookie.

```
export const getJWTCookie = () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (!document.cookie) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const token = document.cookie
    .split("; ")
    .find((row) => row.startsWith(TOKEN_KEY))
    ?.split("=")[1];

  return token;
};
```

The call to the API is made in a page.tsx file as shown below

```
export default async function Cart() {
  const products = await getUserCart();
  console.log(" ~ products:", products);
}
```

Here is getUserCart function

```
import userHTTP from "@/lib/http";
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

export const getUserCart = async (): Promise<IUserCart[] | undefined> => {
  try {
    const res: AxiosResponse = await userHTTP({
      url: "/cart/me",
      method: "GET",
    });

    if (!res) return;

    return res.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(" ~ e:", e);
  }
};
```

However, the response in the console log throws 401 error and while console logging the token in backend I get undefined.

Is there any way I can access the token on the server side(if that's what's causing this issue)

Answer (score 0):

```
// only server components can be `async`
export default async function Cart() {
  const products = await getUserCart();
  console.log(" ~ products:", products);
}
```

you are calling `getUserCart()` in the server component and inside you call `userHTTP` which returns `undefined` on the server. you should write a hook for axios interceptor:

```
const useAxiosHook = () => {
  let cookie = getJWTCookie();

  const userHTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestIntercept = userHTTP.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        if (cookie) {
          config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${cookie}`;
        }
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    // you could also have response interceptor here

    return () => {
      axiosAuth.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
    };
  }, [cookie]);

  return userHTTP;
};

export default useAxiosHook;
```

use this hook in `getUserCart`.

```
export const getUserCart = async (): Promise<IUserCart[] | undefined> => {
  try {
    const userHTTP=useAxiosHook()
    const res: AxiosResponse = await userHTTP({
      url: "/cart/me",
      method: "GET",
    });

    if (!res) return;

    return res.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(" ~ e:", e);
  }
};
```

then turn `Cart` component to client component

```
"use client";

export default async function Cart() {
  const products = await getUserCart();
  console.log(" ~ products:", products);
}
```

Comment: I want to feed data to the Cart which is a page.tsx file meaning I want the data to be fetched on the server, If that makes sense. I don't want it to be a client component. Is that feasible?

Comment: So my axios interceptor should be a hook? Also is axios Interceptor server side or client side?